# How to detect less -R from python

Tags: python, terminal

I can use termcolor[1] to colorize the output from my command-line Python utility. However if piping to "less" or "more" or redirecting to a file the colors show up as an ugly soup of escape codes, basically unreadable.

To address this I can check sys.stdout.isatty() and only colorize if going directly to a terminal. However when piping to "less -R" I do want to colorized, because it can handle it.

Is there a way do use colors if writing to a real terminal *or* if pipeline to a command like "less -R" which can handle colors?

[1] - https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/

Comment: A program doesn't know what happens to its output once it's written, all it can do is detect if stdout appears to be a tty or not. I suggest you give your Python script an option to manually override the result of `sys.stdout.isatty()`, similar to what `ls` does.

Comment: Yeah I have a "force colorized" flag and that works. Was hoping for something better. This seems like a real gap with pipe. Interestingly "head" can deal with non-colorized or colorized output. But "less" cannot, it requires "less -R" if the output is colorized. Seems like less is dumb here.

Comment: If there were a simple way to solve this issue, then `ls` would be using it. It's not so much that `less` is dumb. It's just that by default it assumes you want to read binary data if you feed it binary data. ;)

Comment: Yeah that's too bad. It's pretty lame. If A is sending data to B without knowing what format B wants, it should either have a way to ask B, or it should send both formats and let B decide. Just dreaming here. Thanks for confirmation we as a species still have work to do. Ha.

Comment: I know very little about PowerShell, but I think they try to address this by piping objects between commands not text. Anyway good to confirm this is not possible with Linux so it doesn't keep me up at night.

Comment: One open question. How can `head` with no flags handle colors but `less` requires `-R`. Seems like head is smarter here, it auto-detects, why doesn't less do that? See: https://imgur.com/a/8146qDT